# Producer and consumer missing data

Tags: producer-consumer, producer

In a broadcasting messages system, how the subscriber/clients to know that there are some missing messages, that they fail to receive? Please describe a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is to embed a message counter in each message. The counter allows the consumer to identify missing messages and out of order messages.